# fetch and find frquency count of generalized zipcode

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have table as below

```
ID NAME AGE ZIPCODE
1  A    29   321345
2  B    25   321375
....
```

and so on about 40K records.

I want to fetch distinct zipcodes only upto 4 digits.

like **3213*** include both **(321345 || 321375)**.

So is there any similar clause as **GROUP BY** for this?

Comment: You don't really store age, right?

Comment: well actually original table is bit larger so i have put here 4 columns only.

Comment: Well, let's hope that `age` is not a column in the larger table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only distinct zipcodes(4-digit) is need, use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(zipcodes, 4) ZIPCODE_4_DIGIT FROM tbl
```

If the frequency is also needed, use another:

```
SELECT LEFT(zipcodes, 4) ZIPCODE_4_DIGIT, COUNT(1) FREQUENCY 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ZIPCODE_4_DIGIT;
```

Comment: and any thing for its frequency count?